# JQuery .autocomplete focus doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following Code.

```
function halle(row, settings, row_element) {
    $('input', row).autocomplete({
        minLength: "0",
        source: "../../shared/hallensuche.aspx",
        select: function (e, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            //update hallennr
            var aPos = oTableAnwurfzeiten.fnGetPosition(row_element);
            oTableAnwurfzeiten.fnUpdate(ui.item.value, aPos[0], 11);
            isHalleChanged = true;
            $(this).focus().select();
            return false;
        },
        search: function (e, ui) {
        },
        focus: function (e, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        }
    }).focus(function (e, ui) {
        $(this).autocomplete("option", "source", "../../shared/hallensuche.aspx?focus=true");
        $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
        $(this).select();
        return false;
    }).keydown(function (e, ui) {
        $(this).autocomplete("option", "source", "../../shared/hallensuche.aspx?focus=false" + $('input', row).val());
    });
}
```

If I write something in the input, the keydown command is executed. In .focus nothing happens. When I try an alert(), it works. The autocomplete is not performed so that the "focus = true" is not sent. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: What do you mean *"focus = true" is not sent*? I don't see such code anywhere. Why are do you have two different handlers for focus?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `focusin` instead of focus. The Updated code will look like,

```
$('input', row).autocomplete({
        minLength: "0",
        source: "../../shared/hallensuche.aspx",
        select: function (e, ui) {

        },
        search: function (e, ui) {
        },
        focus: function (e, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        }
    }).on("focusin",function (e, ui) {
       console.log("trigger here");
    }).keydown(function (e, ui) {

    });
```

See the Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32Bck/220/).

Comment: no change. Although I get the console.log, however, the autocomplete not run. in the network analysis of firefox under XHR does't perform post. only when he goes into the keydown